# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'ictinder'

Tags: php, laravel

So for some reason I get this error in my browser when using Laravel. I feel like I got everything set up correctly:

This is my **.env** file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ictinder
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

This is my **database.php** file:

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'ictinder'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

[image: This is a screenshots from my phpMyAdmin, it's Dutch so if you don't understand something, let me know]

This is a screenshots from my phpMyAdmin, it's Dutch so if you don't understand something, let me know

[image: This is what the error looks like in my browser]

This is what the error looks like in my browser

Thank you for taking your time to help out, or at least read my question!

**EDIT 1:**

I already tried php artisan cache:clear and php artisan config:clear, both didn't work. I **can** use php artisan migrate.

Comment: are you using vagrant for development?

Comment: @PKeidel yes I am

Comment: There's your problem then. 127.0.0.1 in a VM (vagrant) will look for a database in the same VM, but your database isn't in your VM.

Comment: that's is weird to hear because I never had this issue with previous databases. But now I have another problem I have to fix, my entire app broke after I tried to **php artisan config:cache**

Comment: @devk do you happen to know how I can make it so it will look for a database outside my VM? Or how to make a database inside the VM? Sorry if these questions are really noobie, I'm very new to all of this

Comment: No, unfortunately. Never done it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using vagrant to run your project. you have to change your db port into `33060` and change your db username into `homestead`

if you are running your program using `php artisan serve`, your db port should be `3306` into your db username

see the docs [laravel homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead)

Hope this can help you

Comment: when I try this both my app and php artisan migrate break. Thanks though!

Comment: do you use homestead?

Comment: yes I do, but when I try to change 3306 into 33060, both my app and php artisan migrate crash

Comment: you have to change your db username too.. lets check my answer

Comment: apologies, my bad. It gave me a different error, but the migrating does work now! I will move ahead with this error and  hopefully fix it. Thanks :)

Comment: Well it says "connection refused", but at least it recognizes the db now and it didnt recognize it before.

Comment: try to `php artisan config:cahe` and try it again

Comment: no that crashes my entire app haha I get this then: "There is no existing directory at "C:\Users\rikro\Homestead\code\ICTinder\storage\logs" and its not buildable: Protocol error"

at least I have a backup

Comment: Okay, If the problem is solved, please do tick. So, the others know that the problem has solved ^^

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do in your case is to remove the `ictinder` from your database and also from your `.eve` file. then recreate the `ictinder` again from where it was been remove, it's adventurous to leave the empty **DB_PASSWORD** like this  `DB_PASSWORD=`, if your MySQL does not have a password, also remember that 
**If you are using the PHP's default web server `(e.g. php artisan serve)` you need to restart your server after changing your `.env` file values.**